# cocos2d cctransitionpageturn

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have 2 problem on `CCTransitionPageTurn`. I target to work on a layer with topLayer and pageLayer. Where topLayer always on top and have menuItem to change page. And pageLayer be content with TurnPage effect.

1. Since I cannot add a `CCScene` over another `CCScene` (i.e. MainScene(CCScene) -> PageScene(CCScene) -> TopLayer(CCLayer) ). So, I think the design will be doing turn page effect on CCLayer (i.e. MainScene(CCScene) -> PageLayer(CCLayer) -> TopLayer(CCLayer) ). But this time `CCTransitionPageTurn` only support `CCScene. Any advice which is a better approach?
2. I see `CCTransitionPageTurn` is turning page at right-bottom corner (forward or backward). But how can I make it at left-bottom corner? Something like flip-X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `CCPageTurn3D` action on the layers, which is actually what drives the `CCTransitionPageTurn`.

Then, to make the page turn from another corner, just subclass `CCPageTurn3D`. Open the source file of `CCPageTurn3D`, and you'll see that it implements a single method. Copy that method to your new subclass, and alter it to make the action take place from any corner you like. If you can't accomplish this, just ask, and I'll help you figure it out.

(**Pro Tip:** when I was new to cocos2d, I'd always forget it's open source, so don't forget that! I figured out this answer by checking the cocos2d source code!)

Comment: thanks, I will try it myself first.
I just look at CCFlipX and want to see if it helps. But you are right, it is open source, why not take full control from it. And learn more from it.